# Selenium_Select value from autopopulate field

Tags: selenium, drop-down-menu

How can we select a value from a field which shows text as auto populate in Selenium Web Driver?

Example :
1. We have a text field.
2. Enter some text like 'ab' in field.
3. It will show a drop down as per text.
4. Now we've to select a value from the drop down through Webdriver.

Could you please help me for the same?

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide html page source.

Comment: What language are your tests written in? What attempts have you made that didn't work?

Comment: I want to write in java. I've no idea for the same. So, Could you please tell me some idea?